# Python Manipulate list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of tuples with the pattern `"id"`, `"text"`, `"language"` like this:

```
a = [('1', 'hello', 'en'), ('1', 'ciao', 'it'), ('2', 'food', 'en'), ('2', 'cibo', 'it')]
```

I would like to create a new tuple (like a table) where I have three columns:

`"id"`, `"en_lang"`, `"it_lang"`.

```
b = [('1', 'hello', 'ciao'), ('2', 'food', 'cibo')]
```

I ask if there is a function that allows me to do this thing.

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) would probably be a good start.

Comment: I tried the code of JuniorCompressor and it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution with yeild and zip:

```
>>> def get_en_it_words(a):
...     for tup1, tup2 in zip(a[0::2], a[1::2]):
...             yield (tup1[0], tup1[1], tup2[1])
... 
>>> a = [('1', 'hello', 'en'),
...  ('1', 'ciao', 'it'),
...  ('2', 'food', 'en'),
...  ('2', 'cibo', 'it')]
>>> list(get_en_it_words(a))
[('1', 'hello', 'ciao'), ('2', 'food', 'cibo')]
```

This should give you all `'en'` words,

```
>>> a[0::2]
[('1', 'hello', 'en'), ('2', 'food', 'en')]
```

And other one `'it'` words,

```
>>> a[1::2]
[('1', 'ciao', 'it'), ('2', 'cibo', 'it')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the items using a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [('1', 'hello', 'en'), ('1', 'ciao', 'it'),
     ('2', 'food', 'en'), ('2', 'cibo', 'it')]

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in a:
    d[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

This can then be converted to a list of tuples like this:

```
b = sorted((k,) + tuple(v) for k, v in d.items())
```

However, you may find the `defaultdict` useful in its own right, since it allows you to easily look up things by `id`.